# How to enable mouse keys on wayland (sway)

Tags: arch-linux, wayland, sway, accessibility

I'm currently on Arch Linux and wanted to know how I could enable mouse keys in wayland (mouse keys as in controlling the mouse with keyboard, the numpad). The arch wiki has mentioned mouse keys under the accessibility section however,I could not find a way to enable this for wayland. I'm using sway as my Window Manager...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Unix & Linux SE. As far as I know, mouse keys is a feature that exists in Gnome and KDE but I couldn't find anything about it in the Sway WM wiki. Are you sure Wayland is the right place to look?